# How to write dictionary list per line in Json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

My script is running fine. The only issue is writing to my Json file.
It dumps all the dictionary in 1 line(the first line)

This is what I try:

```
data = [{'name' : 'Jan', 'age' : '30'}, {'name' : 'Peter', 'age' : '45'}, {'name' : 'Kees', 'age' : '50'}]`
`with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    for d in data:
        json.dump(data, write_file)
```

I expect the output:

```
1 [
2 {"name": "Jan", "age": "30"}, 
3 {"name": "Peter", "age": "45"}, 
4 {"name": "Kees", "age": "50"}
5 ]
```

But I actually get:

```
1 [{"name": "Jan", "age": "30"}, {"name": "Peter", "age": "45"}, {"name": "Kees", "age": "50"}]
2
3
4
5
```

I wanna understand way's how to do what I expect.

Comment: Use `json.dump(data, write_file, indent=2)`. There is no need to loop. Note your loop simply dumped `data` multiple times, re-writing the file wiht the exact same json each time

Comment: If you had done `json.dump(d, write_file)` in a loop, it would have simply given you `{"name": "Kees", "age": "50"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add indentation in you json by using :

```
json.dump(data, write_file, indent=1)
```

This will make your json more readable

The output will be :

```
[
 {
  "name": "Jan",
  "age": "30"
 },
 {
  "name": "Peter",
  "age": "45"
 },
 {
  "name": "Kees",
  "age": "50"
 }
]
```

this is the closest way I could think of

Answer (score -1):

You can pretty print the list using the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) library.

```
from pprint import pprint
d = [{'name' : 'Jan', 'age' : '30'}, {'name' : 'Peter', 'age' : '45'}, {'name' : 'Kees', 'age' : '50'}]
pprint(d)
#Output:
[{'age': '30', 'name': 'Jan'},
 {'age': '45', 'name': 'Peter'},
 {'age': '50', 'name': 'Kees'}]
```

Comment: Is not exactly what I want. I want each dictionary on 1 line.

Comment: This **does not produce  a JSON**

Comment: I posted the `json.dumps` version of my answer before, but that is not what @RaylyEsta wanted. I agree this is not JSON but the OP did not specify that either.